# How do NFC/RFID devices transmit data?

Tags: induction, radio-frequency

I am designing an NFC device but am still a little unsure about the principles behind NFC/RFID. From what I understand:

1. A primary coil constantly emits a 'carrier frequency' magnetic
   field.
2. This field induces an e.m.f. on a passive secondary coil which is in
   a secondary circuit.
3. The secondary circuit comprises a system that converts data into a
   modulation signal, which is realised by a modulating impedance in
   the second circuit.
4. This impedance causes something in the primary circuit to change,
   thus receiving data.

It is step 4. that I am most confused by. Sources I've read simply say the load impedance is "felt" by the primary coil, whatever that means.

Also, what is the function of having a separate transmit and receive antenna on NFC transceivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

When a resonant coil is "unloaded " the current and voltage will be in quadrature (90 degrees out of phase). If you bring a "load" into the vicinity of the coil, this will bring the current more in phase with the voltage (it does work on the load). So if you have a passive secondary coil that can only change how "visible" it is (by changing its impedance) then the primary could can feel this because it sees a phase shift.

The simplest way to change impedance is with a tiny switch that opens and closes the loop, obviously.

I can't answer the part of the question about separate antennas.